# What should my $u$ be for substitution?

Tags: definite-integrals, substitution

$$\int \limits_{\frac 16}^{\frac 12} \csc \left( \frac{\pi}{t} \right) \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{t}\right) \, dt$$

Having trouble deciding on a substitution for this integral .

Comment: If this is a definite-integral (according to your tag), what are the limits of the integral?

Comment: Are you sure there was no $\frac 1{t^2}$ in the integrand.

Comment: Here are the limits , a=1/2 , b=1/6

Comment: I changed the "definite integral" tag to "indefinite integral". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integral diverges. On the other hand, $$\int_{1/2}^{1/6} \csc(\pi t)\cot (\pi t) dt$$ converges and has a nice closed form. I'll assume a typo and show this.

Rewriting $\csc$ and $\cot$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ we obtain $$\int_{1/2}^{1/6}\frac{\cos \pi t}{\sin^2 \pi t}dt=\int_{1/2}^{1/6}\frac{\cos \pi t}{1-\cos^2 \pi t}dt.$$ Now the substitution we need is $u=\cos \pi t \leftrightarrow dt=-1/\pi \displaystyle\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}},$ which produces $$-\frac1\pi\int_{\sqrt{3}/2}^{0}\frac{u}{(1-u^2)^{3/2}}du=\frac1\pi\left\lvert\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right\rvert_0^{\sqrt3/2}=\frac2\pi-\frac1\pi=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac1\pi.} $$

Comment: Substituting $u=\sin\pi t$ in $\int_{1/2}^{1/6}\frac{\cos \pi t}{\sin^2 \pi t}dt$ would have worked too.

Comment: @Marconius: Sure.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you need to write that expression in terms of sine and cosine then you will know how to proceed further from there.

Comment: It suits more a comment than an answer.

Comment: And that isn't the issue here anyway: the integrand is related to the derivative of cosecant.  The problem is in handling the argument of the trig functions properly.

Comment: ok I now have cos(pi/t)/(sin(pi/t)^(2)